# statistical operation in csv file using python

Tags: python

I have `.csv` file and trying to get the average of every 3 lines in turn. meaning lines 1 to 3, then lines 4 to 6 etc. here is a small example:

```
2
5
8
11
14
17
20
23
26
```

and the output I expect to get is:

```
5
14
23
```

I am trying to do that in python and wrote the following code. it does not return what I expect:

```
infile = open("finename.csv", "r")
sum = 0
for i in range(len(infile)):
    if i+(i+1)+(i+2) %3 = 0,
        sum += infile[i]
        average = sum/3
```

do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
import csv
import io

with open("file.csv") as csvFile:
    nbline = 0
    moy = 0
    listMoy = []
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)

    for line in reader:
        moy = moy + int(line[0])
        nbline = nbline + 1
        if nbline == 3:
            moy = moy/3
            print moy
            listMoy.append(moy)
            moy = 0
            nbline = 0

with io.open("fileOut.csv", "w", encoding='UTF-8') as fichier:
    for moy in listMoy:
        fichier.write(u"{0}\n".format(moy))
```

Answer (score 1):

Input file:

```
$ cat a
2
5
8
11
14
17
20
23
26
30
```

Code:

```
counter = 0
sum_value = 0
with open('a', 'r') as fh:
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    sum_value += int(line)
    counter += 1
    if counter == 3:
        print ('%d' % (sum_value / counter))
        sum_value = 0
        counter= 0
```

Output:

```
5
14
23
```

Comment: gives this error:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Base_position,Normalized_Per_Codon,group'

Comment: @john I used the sample input file provided in this question. Pasted the input, code and output that I got.

Comment: @madmatrix: no need for `fh.read().splitlines()`, you can iterate directly over the file itself (and avoid loading the whole damn thing in memory for no good reason).

Comment: Also if you want to remove trailing whitespace(s) / newlines from a string, your want to use `.rstrip()` (ie: `line = line.rstrip()`) instead - FYI in some cases a newline could be two characters (ie the infamous DOS/Windows "CR+LF").

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Did that mistake before. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is weird, you are checking if 3*i + 3 is a multiple of 3, which is always the case.
I would give a step arg to your range to go 3 by 3.

```
infile = open('file.csv', 'r').readlines()
for i in range(2, len(infile), 3):
# starting at two to be sure to have always 3 values to check
    sum = int(infile[i-2]) + int(infile[i-1]) + int(infile[i])
    average = sum/3
    print(average)
```

Comment: here is the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: also I want to make a new csv file for the average.

Comment: My bad, the infile values need to be cast to ints, I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):           #Split readline into subset of 3 elements
        val = map(int, lines[i:i+3])            #Convert elements in list to int
        print(sum(val)/3)                       #Get Avg
```

**Output:**

```
5
14
23
```

Without reading the full file in memory..Thanks @brunodesthuilliers.

```
res = []
temp = []
c = 0
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if c == 3:
            res.append(sum(temp)/3)
            temp = []
            c = 0
        temp.append(int(line))
        c += 1
    if temp:
        res.append(sum(temp)/3)
print(res)
```

Comment: I want to make a new csv file for the results.

Comment: @john then do it. Someone was kind enough to fix your obviously broken code, and instead of thaking him you ask him to do the rest of the job ? Come on, be serious please.

Comment: @Rakesh I would use a lazy iterator (either something from itertools or a custom generator) to avoid loading the whole file in memory.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. Thanks...I did not think of that

Comment: @Rakesh that's what you get from being an old fart - in the 90s no one would ever try to read a whole file in memory (at least not without ensuring it would fit and leave enough space for the system to still work).